# PHP Efficient Form Select for Large Option Sets

Tags: php, forms

I am interested in finding a more efficient way of selecting the proper select option on a select tag with a large amount of options.

The following stripped down example works just fine:

```php
<?php
    $favColor = 'blue';
?>
<form>
    <label for="favColorSelect">Favorite Color:</label>
    <select id="favColorSelect" name="favColorSelect">
        <option value="">Select a Color</option>
        <option value="red" <?php if($favColor === 'red'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Red</option>
        <option value="green" <?php if($favColor === 'green'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Green</option>
        <option value="blue" <?php if($favColor === 'blue'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Blue</option>
    <select>
</form>
```

However, if I am listing a large amount of options, such as time zones, adding this code by hand can be tedious. Is there a better way of going about it?

Comment: Asked so many times. Check the related questions.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I found many that had things similar to my example code, but none that covered a different, more efficient approach. Can you link to one?

Comment: I think Brad have summarized them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can possibly place it in an array/collection you could check with each iteration. Otherwise, what you have is, for all intents and purposes, an adequate way of doing the same.

Tedious maybe, but about typical.

*Iteration Method, for reference:*

```
$colors = array('Red','Green','Blue');
$selColor = 'red';

printf('<selection name="color">');
foreach ($colors as $color){
  printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
    strtolower($color), $color===$selColor?'selected':'', $color);
}
printf('</select>');
```

You can shorten your code by the way (assuming you're allowed to use the short-hand for direct output):

```
<option value="red" <?= ($favColor==='red'?'selected':''); ?>>Red</option>
```